# minidlna still listens on *:<PORT> even though I specify specific network interfaces

Tags: linux

I have minidlna running and want to only have it listening on a particular interface; however, even after configuring it as such, netstat shows otherwise:

```
port=8212
network_interface=eth0,eth1

netstat -patune | grep minidlna

tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8212            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      123        3155724    1222/minidlnad      
udp        0      0 239.255.255.250:1900    0.0.0.0:*                           123        3155723    1222/minidlnad      
udp        0      0 192.168.1.1:33218         0.0.0.0:*                           123        3155732    1222/minidlnad      
udp        0      0 192.168.0.1:31766         0.0.0.0:*                           123        3155729    1222/minidlnad
```

I expect it to be listening only on 192.168.0.1:8212 and 192.168.1.1:8212, but I still see 0.0.0.0:8212.

Comment: Indeed it does. I changed the source when I wanted to do otherwise.

Comment: Ok - what version will be fixed?